# Way to find the flow of tables in db?

Tags: phpmyadmin

i Have to develop a mobile app using same database that is used to develop web app. The Problem is, the db contains more than 30 tables and its very complex cuz it uses some tool like prestashop so is there any tool or anything that can help me to read the flow of table.

P.S: i am viewing the table using phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the schema of PrestaShop 1.5's database here: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Fundamentals+of+PrestaShop+Development#FundamentalsofPrestaShopDevelopment-Databaseschema

The schema for the latest version will be published soon, but the one from your shop should not be very different from the one at the above mentioned page.